# Convert Automapper application to new Ninject project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, automapper, ninject.web.mvc

Our team has inherited a MVC project that uses **Automapper**.  We will be building on top of this project for enhancements.  Overall, it's coded very well and will be a good framework for us.  The issue is we like to use **Ninject** for all our projects.  Stepping through the project's code that uses automapper is taking some time since our experience is very low with automapper.  We ultimately would like to build a new MVC5 project, impliment Ninject, and copy/paste a lot of the code that uses automapper over to the new project which will use Ninject dependency injection.

Has anybody had a similar situation?  Should we get more familiar with **Automapper** and consider not using **Ninject** for this new project?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

---

Ok, after reading up more on Automapper, I think now I got a understanding of how it works.  The way I normally populate my viewmodels are by doing the following:

```
public class Main
{
   public int MainID { get; set; }
   public string MainString { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
  public int Main { get; set; }
  public string MainString { get; set; }
}



[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MainController()
{
  MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
  return View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MainController(MainViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Main objMain = new Main();
    objMain.MainString = model.MainString;
    mainRepository.SubmitMain(objMain);
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

After looking at examples, I notice code such as:

```
MainViewModel model = Mapper.Map<Main, MainViewModel>(mainRepository.GetMain(id));
```

What is the overall benefit of Automapper? Is it just reduce lines of code?

Comment: You do realize that automapper and ninject do totally different things?

Comment: Totally different things?  I thought similar things.

Comment: You might think **autofac**, not automapper